# How can I redirect specific HTTPS request to a backend server using HAPROXY

Tags: haproxy

I have a HTTPS server and want to redirect the specific request based on the URL to my Backend server.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276789/haproxy-redirect-based-on-path/49185050#49185050

Comment: I have one webserver for example https://test.com and I want whenever request goes for https://test.com/video/8.mpd HAPROXY will redirect it to the other server on the specific directory for ex. http://test.internal.com/path/folder/.  So that the requested file by the https://test.com server can be served by the other server.

Comment: Also to simplify any url with .mpd which is coming to https://test.com should redirect to the http://test.internal.com/path/folder/*.ism

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it (for HTTP):

```
frontend http
    bind *:80
    acl mpd path_end -i .mpd
    acl test hdr(host) test.com www.test.com
    use_backend internal if test mpd

backend internal
    http-request set-path /path/folder%[path]
    # for older versions 
    # reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ \/(.+\/)*(.*)\  \1\ /path/to/folder/\3
    server internal-1 internal:80 check
```

Two ACLs in the `frontend` select the right backend and the `http-request` (`reqirep` for older versions) command overwrites the original request path.

You might need to tweak it.

Comment: I made the below configuration:  frontend http
    bind *:80
    acl mpd path_end -i .mpd
    acl test hdr(host) test.usp.com https://test.usp.com
    use_backend internal if test mpd

 backend internal
    http-request set-path /vod/
    server testirdeto.test.com 172.28.1.16:80 check

Comment: But i am getting the error: 
haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
localhost haproxy-systemd-wrapper: [ALERT] 074/121802 (4532) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:108]: 'http-request' expects 'allow', 'deny', 'auth', 'redirect', 'tarpit', 'add-header', 'set-header', 'replace-header', 'replace-value', 'set-nice', 'set-tos', 'set-mark', 'set-log-level', 'add-acl', 'del-acl', 'del-map', 'set-map', but got 'set-path'.
localhost haproxy-systemd-wrapper: [ALERT] 074/121802 (4532) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /

Comment: Which version of HAProxy are you using? `set-path` is introduced in 1.6.

Comment: HA-Proxy version 1.5.18 2016/05/10

Comment: You can use `reqirep` instead. See the updated response. It replaces the path directory, e.g. `/foo/bar/baz.ext` with `/path/to/folder/baz.ext`. Tweak as needed.

Comment: Same error: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: [ALERT] 074/123344 (4585) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:108]: 'http-request' expects 'allow', 'deny', 'auth', 'redirect', 'tarpit', 'add-header', 'set-header', 'replace-header', 'replace-value', 'set-nice', 'set-tos', 'set-mark', 'set-log-level', 'add-acl', 'del-acl', 'del-map', 'set-map', but got 'reqirep'.      I think reqirep is also not supported.Can we try after installing the 1.6 version of HAPROXY?

Comment: You should use `reqirep` **instead of** `http-request`

Comment: After replacing the http-request with reqirep I am successfully able to start the jetty however URL is not redirected to the expected server. How can I confirm that HAPROXY is redirecting or not?

Comment: if you enable `debug` mode you can see the details in the log. You can also pass it as a command line argument to HAProxy.